# Upload file with requests

Tags: python-3.x, file-upload, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I use django rest to upload file

**Serializer**

```
class FileSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    file = serializers.FileField()
```

**View**

```
class FileCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
    serializer_class = api_serializers.FileSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serialize_data = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        if serialize_data.is_valid():
            # save file
        return response
```

Code is work fine with swagger and post man, now I want to upload file with requests module, my code is:

```
files = {"file": open('/home/user/b839.jpeg', 'rb')}
resp = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/api/upload/', files=files)
```

I used this [document](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file). But response content is `{"file": ["No file was submitted."]}`.
 I used `'multipart/form-data'` `Content-Type` either but I get the same response. What is wrong here?

**--Edit--**

Postman generate code snippets:

```
import requests

url = "http://localhost:8000/api/upload/"
payload = "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"123.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--"
headers = {
    'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
    'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "94d50d44-3f06-4e0a-b056"
    }
response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Swagger curl:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' --header 'Accept: application/json' -F file=@"123.jpg"  'http://localhost:8000/api/upload/'
```

Comment: Could you please post the successful queries from swagger and Postman?

Comment: You mean the response?

Comment: No, the requests.

Comment: @Itay4 I post the requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem. Problem was with file dictionary. Value of files dictionary must be a tuple of `(file name, file, content type)` and here is code that worked:

```
files = {"file": ('b839', open('/home/user/b839.jpeg', 'rb'), 'multipart/form-data')}
resp = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/api/upload/', files=files)
```

Answer (score 1):

Removed 'content-type' from the headers